# With Varnish:80 and Nginx:8080 website is 404 not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, cache, varnish

I followed multiple guides how to setup Varnish (e.g. https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/set-up-varnish-ubuntu-16/) and all of them tell to set Varnish to port 80 and Nginx to 8080.

So this is what we see in `netstat -nlpt`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12465/nginx.conf
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12059/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12465/nginx.conf
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12059/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      12059/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6082                :::*                    LISTEN      12059/varnishd
```

This is my site's 100% complete nginx .config:

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  #return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; <--- had to remove this redirect because of the addition to default.vcl, with both enabled it gives infinite redirect loop.
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5';
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;


  root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
    #autoindex on;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
    proxy_read_timeout    90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect        off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

  }

  location ~* /img/.*\.gif$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
}
```

If I go to `example.com`, not just redirects to https and www are broken, I simply get 404 not found. And all I did in my .conf was change 80 to 8080 at the top line.

Also Varnish is actually caching the 404 `curl --head -I example.com`

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.11.10
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:01:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 170
X-Varnish: 72 65
Age: 340
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Cache-Tags: HIT
Connection: keep-alive
```

And to load a website I have to enter `www`.example.com it redirects to `https://www.example.com`, site loads, but Varnish is not caching it `curl --head -I https://www.example.com`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.11.10
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:09:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 478
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 17:30:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "58a73323-1de"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Also `varnishd` gives `Error: Cannot open socket: :80: Address already in use`

`varnishstat` looks good:

```
MAIN.uptime                                                                                                                       0+00:30:07
MAIN.sess_conn                                                                                                                            44          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.client_req                                                                                                                           74          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.cache_hit                                                                                                                            70          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.cache_miss                                                                                                                            4          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.backend_reuse                                                                                                                         3          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.backend_recycle                                                                                                                       6          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.fetch_length                                                                                                                          6          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.pools                                                                                                                                 2          0.00           .            2.00          2.00          2.00
MAIN.threads                                                                                                                             200          0.00           .          200.00        200.00        200.00
MAIN.threads_created                                                                                                                     200          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.n_object                                                                                                                              4          0.00           .            4.00          4.00          4.00
MAIN.n_objectcore                                                                                                                          5          0.00           .            5.00          5.00          5.00
MAIN.n_objecthead                                                                                                                          6          0.00           .            6.00          6.00          6.00
MAIN.n_backend                                                                                                                             1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00          1.00
MAIN.s_sess                                                                                                                               44          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.s_req                                                                                                                                74          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.s_fetch                                                                                                                               4          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.s_req_hdrbytes                                                                                                                    24.54K         0.00         13.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.s_resp_hdrbytes                                                                                                                   15.99K         0.00          9.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.s_resp_bodybytes                                                                                                                  11.46K         0.00          6.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.backend_req                                                                                                                           6          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.n_vcl                                                                                                                                 1          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
MAIN.bans                                                                                                                                  1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00          1.00
MAIN.vmods                                                                                                                                 2          0.00           .            2.00          2.00          2.00
MGT.uptime                                                                                                                        0+00:30:07
SMA.s0.c_req                                                                                                                              12          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
SMA.s0.c_bytes                                                                                                                          2.68K         0.00          1.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
SMA.s0.c_freed                                                                                                                           908          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
SMA.s0.g_alloc                                                                                                                             8          0.00           .            8.00          8.00          8.00
SMA.s0.g_bytes                                                                                                                          1.80K         0.00           .            1.80K         1.80K         1.80K
SMA.s0.g_space                                                                                                                        256.00M         0.00           .          256.00M       256.00M       256.00M
VBE.boot.default.bereq_hdrbytes                                                                                                         1.61K         0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.default.beresp_hdrbytes                                                                                                         936          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.default.beresp_bodybytes                                                                                                       1020          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.default.conn                                                                                                                      6          0.00           .            6.00          6.00          6.00
VBE.boot.default.req                                                                                                                       6          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
```

UPDATE:

Followed https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/09/https-everywhere-with-nginx-varnish-apache/ and added these to config:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
proxy_read_timeout    90;
proxy_connect_timeout 90;
proxy_redirect        off;

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

and these to .vcl

```
# handles redirecting from http to https
sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
    return(deliver);
  }
}

if ( (req.http.host ~ "^(?i)smashing_ssl_one.tutorials.eoms") && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
  set req.http.x-redir = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
  return (synth(750, ""));
}
```

Still 404, but at least varnish is caching `https://` now.

```
curl -I https://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.11.10
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 12:58:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 170
Connection: keep-alive
X-Varnish: 32849 32847
Age: 63
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache: HIT
```

Also while `https://www.example.com/` is 404 not found, but e.g. `https://www.example.com/img/pic.png` is found and loads item, but not varnished.

Comment: Varnish does not support HTTPS,

Comment: Well, does varnish listen on port 443? According to your config, it's only nginx that listen to it.
Check it with "netstat -ltpn".

Comment: Your virtualhost does not contain that information. Please update the question with the correct virtualhost

Comment: It's updated. Also had to comment out first 301 redirect because of the addition to the default.vcl with both of them on, it gives infinite redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below nginx configuration for 443 proxy

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;

       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
       ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_connect_timeout       86400;
            proxy_send_timeout          86400;
            proxy_read_timeout          86400;
            send_timeout                86400;
            client_max_body_size 50m;
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
}
        location /.git {
            deny all;
            return 404;
        }
}
```